# Could not open requirements file in github actions

Tags: python, github, github-actions

I am trying to setup a github workflow (first time)

but keep getting this error

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
Error: ERROR: Action failed during dependency installation attempt with error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.12/x64/bin/python' failed with exit code 1
```

you can view my director structure [here](https://github.com/codewithnick/searchenginepy)
and github workflow file

```
name: testing
on: [push,pull_request]
run-name: running tests for searchenginepy
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10' # install the python version needed
          
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: py-actions/py-dependency-install@v4
        with:
              path: "requirements.txt"
          
      - name: run tests # run main.py
        working-directory: tests
        run: python -m unittest discover
```

I have tried

> pip install .
> pip install -r .github/workflows/requirements.txt

I am also not sure about the unittest directory because that needs to be run in the tests folder

Comment: You never check out your code

Comment: sorry did not understand

Comment: Then I'd suggest looking at e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions - compare your workflow to their examples.

Comment: check https://github.com/marketplace/actions/checkout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please just add checkout step `- uses: actions/checkout@v3`

```
name: testing
on: [push,pull_request]
run-name: running tests for searchenginepy
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10' # install the python version needed
          
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: py-actions/py-dependency-install@v4
        with:
              path: "requirements.txt"
          
      - name: run tests # run main.py
        working-directory: tests
        run: python -m unittest discover
```